# Issues with compiling ARM binary for STM on Apple MAC book

Tags: c, arm, cross-compiling, stm32, gnu-toolchain

I am trying to compile a project on Mac but I am getting lots of errors. It compiles fine on Linux. I reference the toolkit included with STM workshop.

When running `cmake ../.. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../../tools/toolchain/nucleo_f746zg.cmake` from /build/debug, I get the following output..

```
/var/folders/fg/ldkpxwvn45v5y854s4zsw_b00000gn/T//ccBDWJKO.s:404: Error: selected processor does not support `dsb' in ARM mode
/var/folders/fg/ldkpxwvn45v5y854s4zsw_b00000gn/T//ccBDWJKO.s:407: Error: selected processor does not support `isb' in ARM mode
make[2]: *** [platform/nucleo-f746zg/CMakeFiles/alesi-platform-nucleo-f746zg.dir/osal/freertos/os_context.c.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [platform/nucleo-f746zg/CMakeFiles/alesi-platform-nucleo-f746zg.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error
```

Does anyone have advice for this? How can I compile the code for ARM?
I am running ARM GNU tools and using arm-none-eabi-g++ and arm-none-eabi-gcc compilers.

Comment: Why are you using two compilers Gcc and g++, is it the requirement for you? Seems by default your configuration enables dsp mode you need to check who is doing that in your build script.

Answer (score 1):

The STM32 family of microcontrollers is based on Cortex cores, they're not able to run ARM instructions set, they use Thumb-1 and Thumb-2.

For the STM32F4 family I use flags like `-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16`.

The [readme.txt from gcc-arm-embedded](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/287100883/readme.txt) can give you some hints on how to select the most appropriate flags for your target architecture.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner just install a ready made IDE with toolchain. Google for openSTM32. It is an eclipse + plugins + toolchain.

It will save you many days of googling and configuring